# How to safely use unique_ptr with functions which can return NULL?

Tags: c++, c++14, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I've noticed that this compiles:

```
#include<memory>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    unique_ptr<int>a(nullptr);
    if(!a)
    cout<<"NULLPTR";
}
```

However, this doesn't:

```
#include<memory>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    unique_ptr<int>a(NULL);
    if(!a)
    cout<<"NULL";
}
```

I'm working with a library which has [several functions which return a raw pointer](https://datastax.github.io/cpp-driver/api/struct.CassSession/) and those have to be manually freed after their use. I want to use unique_ptr(with custom deleter) to manage such raw pointers. 
I was worried about those cases when those functions return NULL as I think that might cause some problems.

Comment: `NULL` isn't the problem; it's what you do with it. A function return `Type*` is typed to the caller, whether it returns `NULL`, `nullptr` (which you *should* be using), or whatever. Odd that you asked about "function which can return `NULL`", but posted no such function as an example exhibiting your worry.

Comment: @WhozCraig I've added the link of the library I'm using. You can check the first function given on the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's fine. It's just the `NULL` macro (which expands to just `0` on most compilers) that's causing the problem. `0` matches both the `nullptr_t` and `T*` constructors of `unique_ptr`, so it's ambiguous and won't compile.

When initializing a `unique_ptr` with a pointer variable or the return value of a function, it doesn't matter whether `nullptr`, `NULL` or `0` was used. They all have the same effect: a null pointer:

This is perfectly fine, for example

```
int* int_p1 = NULL;
int* int_p2 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));

unique_ptr<int, decltype(&free)> a1(int_p1, free);
unique_ptr<int, decltype(&free)> a2(int_p2, free);
```

Note: if you're not interfacing with C functions that used `malloc()` to allocate, but with C++ functions that used `new`, do not use custom deleters. The default deleter of `unique_ptr` already uses `delete`.

Answer (score 3):

`NULL` is an obsolete *null pointer constant* that is deprecated in favor of `nullptr`. Both constants designate the same thing, a null pointer *value*. These constants are compile time constructs.

`NULL` is deprecated because apart from designating a null pointer value, it also designates the integer zero, depending on context. (It is a macro defined as `0`). This is dangerous and error prone, so `unique_ptr` specifically disallows it.

At run time, a function cannot possibly return a null pointer constant, which belongs to a totally wrong category of things. It returns a null pointer value. At that time, there is neither `NULL` nor `nullptr`.